# DDMathParser gives memory leak

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ddmathparser

I am using DDMathParser in my Xcode project. I have a memory leak and I can't resolve it.

Instruments gives me following leaked objects:
_DDNumberExpression
_DDFunctionExpression

Can anyone help me?

My code for using ddmathparser:

```
NSString *result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [string numberByEvaluatingString]];
```

Comment: Not without seeing the code. If you haven't already done so, you should consider switching to ARC.

Comment: Is this leak on the device or the simulator. If it's the simulator, test again on a real device :) The simulator sometimes gives false readings.

Comment: And what does the analyser tell you - do you get any warnings when you run it?

Comment: I hope that @DaveDeLong will see your question at some point, [he's the author of DDMathParser](http://stackoverflow.com/users/115730/dave-delong) :):):)

Comment: `[self setInvestigating:YES];`  Also, please post what the contents of `string` is.

Answer (score 2):

DDMathParser author here.

I sure hope this isn't a leak in my code, but if the reproduction case is as simple as you say it is, then it's sure possible.  The static analyzer isn't showing me any problems with the code, but the static analyzer also isn't perfect.

Here's what I need to debug this:

1. What is `string`?  It's obviously an `NSString` variable, but I need to know the contents
2. Are you doing anything else with `DDMathParser`, or is it just this one line?

---

**Edit**

From your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12271473/115730), I saw that you were using the string `@"1+2"`.  When I run that code in Instruments, I get no leaks (both with ARC and without).  So yeah, I'm going to need a lot more information.

Comment: I've made a [screenshot](http://img826.imageshack.us/img826/1441/instrumentsf.png) for you.

Comment: I'm not doing anything else with it. It's just this one line. I've tested it in a complete new Xcode project but with ARC I always get the same memory leaks.